# Navigation Stack : Speed of Robot

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So finally got things working, again people on here are awesome and I am actually now reading a book on ROS to fill in the gaps.

I used code from https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/navigation2d_example

Parameters on the Robot seem to be in
https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/navigation2d_example/blob/master/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml
https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/navigation2d_example/blob/master/param/costmap_common_params.yaml

My question is, does either of these files control the turning speed of the robot as it is struggling to turn on carpet?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252799/navigation-stack-:-speed-of-robot/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the file `base_local_planner_params.yaml` will control the turning speed (as well as the longitudinal speed). Specifically, the parameters: `max_vel_theta`, `min_vel_theta`, and `min_in_place_vel_theta`. These are standard parameters for the base_local_planner package. You will find their definitions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner#Parameters).

The second file you reference contains parameters for the costmap, which you can read more about [here](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d).

However, the maximum velocity setting may not be you problem. When turning on carpet you could be power limited, or also be experiencing excessive slip, which will not only lengthen the turning time, but also add time just for the localization to realize the robot has not turned sufficiently far.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-24**:
Thanks for the help, thats awesome!

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-24**:
When you say power limited are you saying the motors are not powerful enough?

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2017-01-24**:
It is possible. But without knowing anything about your robot I can't say for sure, I just though I would mention it since you emphasized the behaviour on carpet. A robot with small wheels, weak motors, and on plush carpet, could have difficulty moving.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-24**:
Thank you, could I ask if max_vel_theta = 1 does that mean 100% power?

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2017-01-24**:
No, that means 1 radians/sec. As per the definition of max_vel_theta on the base_local_planner link I provided: "The maximum rotational velocity allowed for the base in radians/sec".

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-24**:
Oh sorry I am pretty new to this, Now I just need to work out the actual value :)

**Comment by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) on 2017-01-24**:
No worries. Just always try to look at the documentation for whatever you are doing. Most information you need is usually there.